# ui.router including partials inside head

Tags: angularjs

I have the following template loaded with PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
      <div ui-view="head"></div>
      <title>Main page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ui-view="body"></div>
      <div ui-view="scripts"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I now want to define head, body, and scripts partials individually for each route. I did this, but I can't insert a view to the div inside the head element - it's not valid, and it doesn't work anyways.

How can I do this?

```
$stateProvider
        .state('list', {
            url: '/fooBar/list',
            views: {
                'body': { 
                    templateUrl: 'list.html',
                    controller: 'ListCtrl'
                },
                'head': {
                    templateUrl: 'head.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you want to put in the `<head>` section. No HTML should be placed there other than scripts and meta tags.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the head?